# Excel files downloaded from Gmail with no extension?

Tags: microsoft-excel, google-chrome, gmail

I downloaded a excel file from my gmail account attachment. 
When I downloaded it, the file showing without "**.xlsx** or **.xls**" extensions.
I renamed it by adding "**.xlsx**" at the ending. and it works.

And when I downloaded the same file in other computer (which is of my colleague) it downloaded perfectly, i.e., with extension "**.xlsx**".

So is it a problem of my chrome or Microsoft Office or my Windows files or any other.

Please kindly help on this thing.

Comment: Have you simply set your Windows/File Explorer view options to hide extensions?

Comment: Yeah, I know that, But when I downloaded it showing as a file. Not as Excel file symbol. Today, I noticed that, only that attachment is downloading without extension. In other computer all computer works normal.

Comment: It appears you are using a different account than the one with which you posted the question. Go to https://superuser.com/contact and merge your user profiles.

Answer (score 1):

Judith's right; (File) Explorer can be set to hide extensions. In Explorer, click on View then look to the right; is **Hide File Extensions** checked?

[image]

If so, uncheck it.

Now that file will be named *whatever*.xlsx.xlsx